# Generic nested types: cannot convert from X<T> to X<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a class for working with undirected graphs, and encountered the following compile-time errors:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Dictionary.EdgeCollection>.Add(TVertex, UndirectedGraph.EdgeCollection)'
>   has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert
>   from `UndirectedGraph<TVertex,TEdge>.AdjacentEdgeCollection<TVertex,TEdge>`
>     to `UndirectedGraph<TVertex,TEdge>.AdjacentEdgeCollection<TVertex,TEdge>`

I could reduce the problem to the following example:

```
public class UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge>
{
    Dictionary<TVertex, EdgeCollection<TVertex, TEdge>> edges;

    class VertexCollection<TVertex, TEdge>
    {
        UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph;

        public VertexCollection(UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph)
        { this.graph = graph; }

        public void Add(TVertex value)
        {
            // Argument 2: cannot convert
            // from 'UndirectedGraph<TVertex,TEdge>.AdjacentEdgeCollection<TVertex,TEdge>'
            //   to 'UndirectedGraph<TVertex,TEdge>.AdjacentEdgeCollection<TVertex,TEdge>'
            this.graph.edges.Add(value, new EdgeCollection<TVertex, TEdge>(this.graph));
        }
    }

    class EdgeCollection<TVertex, TEdge>
    {
        public EdgeCollection(UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph) { }
    }
}
```

Note that `TVertex` and `TEdge` in the nested classes are different from `TVertex` and `TEdge` in the outer class, and I get warnings stating that I should rename them. I can do that, but this does not affect the errors. I think the purpose of the fragment is clear, so how do I get it to do what I want and where does my thinking go wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your intent? It *looks* as if you should not make `VertexCollection` and `EdgeCollection` "double-generic" and that you should just use the outer `TVertex` and `TEdge` in the nested classes as well.

Comment: @harold that is the intent of my answer also; I had not seen you comment when I posted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that there are three `TVertex` type parameters and three `TEdge` type parameters? It seems to me that that all three are same and what you need is the following:

```
public class UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge>
{
    Dictionary<TVertex, EdgeCollection> edges;

    class VertexCollection
    {
        UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph;

        public VertexCollection(UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph)
        { this.graph = graph; }

        public void Add(TVertex value)
        {
            this.graph.edges.Add(value, new EdgeCollection(this.graph));
        }
    }

    class EdgeCollection
    {
        public EdgeCollection(UndirectedGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph) { }
    }
}
```